# AMPscript Personalization Strings - email address

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Is there are a Personalization String that can be used to pull in the email address that a given Journey is being targeted at?

I'm pulling in the email address from a Data Extension using the "Use email attribute from Contacts" functionality.

%%emailaddr%% will only pull in the main email address associated with a Subscriber.  But in certain cases I need to pull in other email addresses associated with a Subscriber.

Salesforce have [this documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_available_personalization_strings.htm&type=5), but I'm not sure if the list in this is exhaustive.

Comment: Just write an AMPScript LookUp that pulls in this information from that particular dataextension and display the variable like `%%=v(@variablename)=%%`

Comment: If you are using 'email attribute from Contacts' then %%emailaddr%% should pull that email. This personalization string pulls the assigned sendable Email Address, which in that case would be the email address stored in All Subscribers or 'the main email address'.  If you want an email address that is not the sendable one, then you would need to use the field name that is stored in the sendable data (e.g. `%%secondary_email%%`) OR do a lookup to the DE to gather that email. E.g. `Lookup('myDE', 'EmailAddress','SubscriberKey',_SubscriberKey)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an assumption that this resolved his issue, I am transferring this from a comment to an answer for easy reference:

If you are using 'email attribute from Contacts' then `%%emailaddr%%` should pull that email. This personalization string pulls the assigned sendable Email Address, which in that case would be the email address stored in All Subscribers or 'the main email address'.

If you want an email address that is not the sendable one, then you would need to use the field name that is stored in the sendable data (e.g. `%%secondary_email%%` if stored in field name secondary_email) OR do a lookup to the DE to gather that email. E.g. `Lookup('myDE', 'EmailAddress','SubscriberKey',_SubscriberKey)`.